# Is it possible to automatically verify that an "In Source Suppression" suppresses something?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, suppress-warnings

I use In Source Suppression messages whenever possible and reasonable. The next time I run the code analysis, methods which violate static analysis rules (for which they are suppressed) will not show up as violations.

However, methods with suppression messages do not necessarily violate the the rules which are being suppressed. It could be due to a refactoring, a bad copy-paste or changes elsewhere in the code.

Besides manually running the code analysis with and without each suppression message, is there an automated way to tell which are the superfluous suppression messages, just like how warnings are given for unresolved references in XML documentation comments?